# SQL Error - Multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a horizontal output of the data in format

The query is:

```
SELECT RDT1.County_Name
      ,RDT1.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT1.Vac_Allocated
      ,RDT1.Priority,RDT2.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT2.Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated
      ,RDT3.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT3.Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated 
FROM Result_Distribution_Table AS RDT1
    ,Result_Distribution_Table AS RDT2
    ,Result_Distribution_Table AS RDT3 
WHERE RDT1.County_Name = RDT2.County_Name AND
      RDT1.DistributionNumber = 1 AND 
      RDT2.DistributionNumber = 2 AND 
      RDT3.DistributionNumber = 3 AND 
      RDT1.County_Name = RDT3.County_Name 
WHERE Solution_id= "10"
```

When I execute this query, I get a response

> *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   The multi-part identifier "Solution_id" could not be bound.*

`Solution_id` is a column in the `Result_Distribution_Table` table.

Please help as to what i am doing wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: Did you mean to have two `WHERE` statements in your query?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one `WHERE` clause per query. Also avoid using old style joining instead use `JOIN`. **NOTE:** fill the correct table alies for the `solution_id` col.

```
SELECT RDT1.County_Name
      ,RDT1.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT1.Vac_Allocated
      ,RDT1.Priority,RDT2.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT2.Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated
      ,RDT3.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
      ,RDT3.Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated 
FROM Result_Distribution_Table RDT1 JOIN  Result_Distribution_Table RDT2
      ON RDT1.County_Name = RDT2.County_Name JOIN Result_Distribution_Table RDT3 
      ON RDT1.County_Name = RDT3.County_Name
WHERE RDT1.DistributionNumber = 1 AND 
      RDT2.DistributionNumber = 2 AND 
      RDT3.DistributionNumber = 3 AND 
      [...].Solution_id= "10"
```

**ADDING:** Just noticed that you are using same table 3 times. **If it is the case** you can get the same results as;

```
SELECT County_Name
          ,DistributionNumber as Dist_No
          ,Vac_Allocated
          ,Priority,RDT2.DistributionNumber as Dist_No
          ,Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated
          ,DistributionNumber as Dist_No
          ,Vac_Allocated as Vac_Allocated 
FROM Result_Distribution_Table 
WHERE DistributionNumber IN (1,2,3) AND
          Solution_id= "10"
```

Comment: The second query has an orphan `RDT2` table reference, never mind the fact that you can't get the same output from one table reference anyways (or not without something like `PIVOT`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is  because there is no table  in the query:

It looks like you forgot to include the table in your query.